# How to have two owners access the same files

Tags: permission, filesystem, mojave

I'm trying to give full access to two different users in the same directory.

When I run Laravel via Apache, it uses the `_www` user. When I run Laravel via PHPUnit (on the command line), it uses my own user. At some point I managed to add the user `_www` to my Laravel `storage/` directory so it has access to all the files. However, now it has created some of its own files that can't be accessed when running tests. How can I get both users to have full access to all current and future files in `storage/`?

This is the output of `ls -ale storage/framework/views/`:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 22 administrator  wheel    704 23 Nov 12:33 .
 0: user:_www allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxr-x+  7 administrator  wheel    224  4 Sep 23:12 ..
 0: user:_www allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
-rw-rw-r--+  1 administrator  wheel     14  4 Sep 23:12 .gitignore
 0: user:_www allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
-rw-rw-r--   1 _www           wheel    564 27 Sep 12:18 6cb8d6ae8cab36b3c68a6e462a5bf6ea6343e382.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 administrator  wheel    580 22 Nov 14:59 90839493114c3ceef215929146f8be634f4674a5.php
```

When the test tries to write to `6cb8d6ae8cab36b3c68a6e462a5bf6ea6343e382.php`, it fails due to a permissions error, because it was created by and belongs to the other user.